# Material-UI FAB: How can I increase the size of the button without ruining its responsive design?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm trying to make the FAB a bit bigger than what it is under "large" and when I tried to change width/height, I noticed that the responsive design was ruined. What is the correct way to change width & height of the FAB without ruining the responsive design?

Comment: just increase the font size of inner content of fab button.. it will automatically increase the button size without giving the width and height